# Simply Responsive Image Hover using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am a newbie programming and need some help of the pro's here.

I am using bootstrap for building a new Website. Below my Slier I want to add 2 Rows and 2 Columns.

- (1st Row - 1st Column: col-lg-8, 2nd Column: col-lg-4)
- (2st Row - 1st Column: col-lg-6, 2nd Column: col-lg-6)

For each column, I want to use a different (full-width-row) background-image and a text box. This is the **layout before the user is hovering over the elements**. As you can see there is some spacing between the images and a text box with white background and some text:

[image: layout]

The second screenshot is showing the **image when the customer is hovering over a picture**. As you can see. when the customer is hovering over a picture of the grid just the overlay for the picture is changing to a darkish grey. the text box and its content is still white.

[image: layout hover]

Guys, I want to thank you and I hope we will find a solution. Cheeeeers and greetings from Berlin!

Comment: Can you add the relevant (and only the relevant) parts of your code to the question so we can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the image inside a `div` (with a black background) and then on image hover, set the image `opacity` to about `0.7`.

```css
.fade {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fade p {
  /* Prevent paragraph from changing .fade size (set position) */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 5px;
  /* Set z-index to prevent image covering */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Set background */
  background-color: white;
}

.fade img {
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  display: block;
}

.fade img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover the image</p>

<div class="fade">
  <p>This won't be faded</p>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&bg=ffffff&txtclr=000000&txt=250%C3%97250&w=250&h=250"></img>
</div>
```